Getting object from MinIO bucket within AWS Signature authentication
Running following Bash script to get object from MinIO bucket within AWS Signature authentication and keep getting error "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method." Every step is implemented following instructions from AWS website https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_sigv-create-signed-request.html Same configuration with Postman working fine. What could be a problem with script code or structure?
#!/bin/bash

# MinIO credentials and details
HTTP_METHOD="GET"
SERVICE="s3"
HOST="192.168.1.18:9000"
REGION="us-east-1"
ENDPOINT="https://${HOST}"
ACCESS_KEY="*************"
SECRET_KEY="*******************************"
BUCKET_NAME="small"
OBJECT_KEY="test15K.txt"
PAYLOAD="UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD"
REQUEST_TYPE="aws4_request"

# Date and time settings
DATE=$(date -u "+%Y%m%d")
TIMESTAMP=$(date -u "+%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")

######################################
# STEP # 1: Create canonical request #
######################################
HASHED_PAYLOAD=$(echo -n "" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}')
CANONICAL_URI="/${BUCKET_NAME}/${OBJECT_KEY}"
CANONICAL_QUERY_STRING=""
CANONICAL_HEADERS=$(printf "host:%s\nx-amz-date:%s\nx-amz-content-sha256:%s\n" "${HOST}" "${TIMESTAMP}" "${HASHED_PAYLOAD}")

SIGNED_HEADERS="host;x-amz-date;x-amz-content-sha256"
CANONICAL_REQUEST=$(printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s" "${HTTP_METHOD}" "${CANONICAL_URI}" "${CANONICAL_QUERY_STRING}" "${CANONICAL_HEADERS}" "${SIGNED_HEADERS}" "${HASHED_PAYLOAD}")

HASHED_CANONICAL_REQUEST=$(printf "%s" "${CANONICAL_REQUEST}" | openssl dgst -sha256 | awk '{print $2}')

#######################################
# STEP # 2: Create the string to sign #
#######################################
ALGORITHM="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
CREDENTIAL_SCOPE="${DATE}/${REGION}/${SERVICE}/${REQUEST_TYPE}"
STRING_TO_SIGN=$(printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s" "${ALGORITHM}" "${TIMESTAMP}" "${CREDENTIAL_SCOPE}" "${HASHED_CANONICAL_REQUEST}")

#####################################
# STEP # 3: Calculate the signature #
#####################################
DATE_KEY=$(echo -n "${DATE}" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt key:"AWS4${SECRET_KEY}" | awk '{print $2}')
DATE_REGION_KEY=$(echo -n "${REGION}" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt key:"${DATE_KEY}" | awk '{print $2}')
DATE_REGION_SERVICE_KEY=$(echo -n "${SERVICE}" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt key:"${DATE_REGION_KEY}" | awk '{print $2}')
SIGNING_KEY=$(echo -n "${REQUEST_TYPE}" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt key:"${DATE_REGION_SERVICE_KEY}" | awk '{print $2}')
SIGNATURE=$(echo -n "${STRING_TO_SIGN}" | openssl dgst -sha256 -mac HMAC -macopt key:"${SIGNING_KEY}" | awk '{print $2}')

####################################################
# STEP # 4: Add signing information to the request #
####################################################
AUTHORIZATION_HEADER="${ALGORITHM} Credential=${ACCESS_KEY}/${CREDENTIAL_SCOPE}, SignedHeaders=${SIGNED_HEADERS}, Signature=${SIGNATURE}"

curl -X GET "${ENDPOINT}/${BUCKET_NAME}/${OBJECT_KEY}" \
-H "X-Amz-Content-Sha256:${HASHED_PAYLOAD}" \
-H "X-Amz-Date:${TIMESTAMP}" \
-H "Authorization:${AUTHORIZATION_HEADER}" -k


Btw.: variable PAYLOAD is unused.

This might help: How to debug a bash script?

There is conflicting report from different sources what should be sent to AWS Signature
HASHED_PAYLOAD=$(echo -n "" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}')
VS.
HASHED_PAYLOAD=$(echo -n "${PAYLOAD}" | sha256sum | awk '{print $1}')
